# What happens to Fortran scratch files when a program terminates early?

Tags: file, fortran

Specifically I'd like to know if scratch files in Fortran are deleted if a program terminates (or is killed) before issuing the `close()` on the scratch unit.

Comment: What happened when you investigated this ?

Answer (score 2):

The Fortran standard says the file is deleted on "**normal** termination of the program". While many implementations may try to delete scratch files on abnormal termination, I don't recommend depending on this. In particular, if you "kill" the program, it is much less likely that scratch files will get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Just created a test code to answer my question. I ran the code below on my OS X Mac using the Intel iFort compiler. iFort puts the scratch files in $TMPDIR, and the test shows the scratch file there during the pause. The scratch file disappears when the program exits normally and also when it is terminated with a ctrl-c. This will be useful for an MPI program I have that writes many GB of temporary files to local scratch space since I don't want those files to persist if the program is terminated early by the user or the scheduler.

```
program test

open(unit=20,status='scratch')

write(20,*) (i, i = 1,100000)

write(*,*) 'pausing, type ls -la $TMPDIR/f* to see the scratch file'
write(*,*) 'hit enter to continue or ctrl-c to interrupt and stop'
read(*,*) 

close(20)

end
```